How can I select the proper ssh passphrase under cron
I have a couple of ssh clients that I want to automatically set up a ssh-tunnel to a server.
To this end I am using cron and sshpass.
Depending on the history of the server it may for example expect a response to
user@server's password:
Enter passphrase for key '/home/he/.ssh/id_rsa':
or
Enter passphrase for key '/home/he/id_ed25519':
This may change over time.
Now I would like my script to automatically select the correct passphrase.
Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Why encrypt the keys in the first place if you store the passphrase in clear text? Why not just store them unencrypted?

Use keys without passphrase for automation.
To contain the possible impact, restrict them heavily on the target system in authorized_keys. For example, if the key is supposed to be only used to establish the tunnel, I use the following:
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/bin/false" ssh-ed25519 AAAA.... 

I use this for the SOCKS feature in SSH.
The details of how to use this, refer to man authorized_keys.

Thanks
I have tried 2 somewhat simpler ways:

Simply set the prompt to ":" as in

sshpass -P ":"  -v -p"somepassword" ssh -tt -p 6666 -fN -R 7777:localhost:22 someuser@someserver

If you don't like that then extract the entire prompt with:

prompt=$(sshpass -v -P "pass" -p"notapassword" ssh someuser@someserver 2>&1 | sed -n '2 p')

Simplify 2:prompt=$(ssh someuser@someserver 2>&1 | sed -n '2 p')
